# why does python socket library not include recvall() method like sendall()?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

When using recv() method, sometimes we can't receive as much data as we want, just like using send(). But we can use sendall() to solve the problem of sending data, how about receiving data? Why there is no such recvall() method?

Comment: What exactly would "all" mean in the context of "receive all"?

Comment: @NPE It means if i write something like: data = socket.recvall(1024), the length of received data will be exactly 1024. While if I use data = socket.recv(1024), sometimes the received data is less than 1024 bytes.

Comment: That could indeed be useful in some circumstances. It would be trivial to implement in your code though (with a loop around `recv()`).

Comment: Sockets include a `.makefile()` method that wrap the socket in a file-like object.  Then `.readline()` and `.read(n)` are available, where `.read(n)` waits to read n bytes and only returns less on socket close or error.

Answer (score 11):

There is no fundamental reason why such a function could not be provided as part of the standard library. In fact, there has been [at least one attempt to add `recvall()`](http://bugs.python.org/issue1103213).

Given that it can be easily implemented as a loop around `recv()`, I don't think that this is a major omission.

Comment: If you implement it yourself in a loop around `recv` then you can handle it failing in way that suits you. Figuring out what `recvall` should do if `recv` fails is what caused the patch you linked to flounder.

Comment: From my experience looking at python questions with the [socket] tag over the last several years it is a major omission.

Comment: // I don't think that this is a major omission // it does confuse the newcomers though.

Comment: It is *not trivial* to write an optimized loop around `recv`. There are two considerations: (A) overall time complexity and (B) event latency. (A) encourages you to join a list at the end. However, (B) is only affected by the computation after the last packet arrives, so (B) encourages you to join previous packets as they arrive. Conclusion: use `recv_into` and not `recv`, since we know the expected message size in advance and can allocate a buffer.

Answer (score 8):

`send` has extra information that `recv` doesn't: how much data there is to send. If you have 100 bytes of data to send, `sendall` can objectively determine if fewer than 100 bytes were sent by the first call to `send`, and continually send data until all 100 bytes are sent.

When you try to read 1024 bytes, but only get 512 back, you have *no* way of knowing if that is because the other 512 bytes are delayed and you should try to read more, or if there were only 512 bytes to read in the first place. You can never say for a fact that there will be more data to read, rendering `recvall` meaningless. The most you can do is decide how long you are willing to wait (timeout) and how many times you are willing to retry before giving up.

You might wonder why there is an apparent difference between reading from a file and reading from a socket. With a file, you have extra information from the file system about how much data is in the file, so you reliably distinguish between EOF and some other that may have prevented you from reading the available data. There is no such source of metadata for sockets.

Comment: If you are parsing a "type, length, value" protocol you know *exactly* how many bytes you need to read - first enough to read the type and length fields (which will have constant length) and then value which you know how big is from the read header. Any kind of problem with that means a malformed message, so you can safely abort the connection.

Comment: Sure, *if* you are using such a protocol. That's beyond the scope of the `socket` library, though.

Comment: Except that you should use socket library *only* if you're using non-standard protocol... Even HTTP has headers that indicate the size of the body and there are provisions for ACSII-like protocols in standard library (`socket.makefile('r').readline()`). It's silly there are none for binary protocols, in which you *have a way of knowing* how much to read.

Comment: @HubertKario I don't think you appreciate how low-level the `socket` API is. It reads and writes bytes to a black hole: that's it. It doesn't know or care about particular protocols for the data being sent.

Comment: and I don't think you appreciate the fact we're trying to do this in Python. And the first thing you should ask yourself is "how Python can solve my problem", not trying to reinvent the wheel for the n-th time. Irrespective whether you're a library or application developer. If you are writing ASCII based protocol parser it does provide you with the wheel, not so much for the binary protocol.

Comment: Python *might* solve your problem, but `socket` isn't that solution. You need a higher-level library (in the Python library, or provided in a 3rd-party library, or one that you write yourself) that wraps `socket` to handle particular protocols. If you have a specific problem in mind, please start a new question rather than posting in the comments to this answer.

Comment: I have a problem with your answer, in which you assume _a priori_ that @flymike has no way of knowing how much data will the other side provide. It's a bad answer and I explained in the other comments why, and why the question being asked is entirely valid.

Comment: Then, please, down vote it and move on. I am not going to try to convince you further that `socket` isn't intended to be the final answer to all network-related communication problems.

Answer (score -1):

Because `recvall` is fundamentally confusing: your assumption was that it would read exactly-N bytes, but I would have thought it would completely exhaust the stream, based on the name.

An operation that completely exhausts the stream is a dangerous API for a bunch of reasons, and the ambiguity in naming makes this a pretty unproductive API.