# Python grab all UDP Datagrams

Tags: python, tcp, udp

Server.py ish

```
import random
import pickle
import time
import socket
num=random.random()
data=pickle.dumps(num)
now=time.time()
mail={'d':data,'t':now}
box=pickle.dumps(mail)
UDP_IP = socket.gethostname()
UDP_PORT = 42096
place=(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT)
tube = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
tube.sendto(box, place)

import threading
randomnumstreamgo=True
def randomnumstreamloop():  #This sends a random number to 42069 every 10 seconds
    global randomnumstreamgo
    while randomnumstreamgo:
        num=random.random()
        data=pickle.dumps(num)
        now=time.time()
        mail={'d':data,'t':now}
        box=pickle.dumps(mail)
        tube.sendto(box, place)
        delay=10
        time.sleep(delay)
    randomnumstream=True

randomnumstreamloophandler=[[thread,thread.start()] for thread in [threading.Thread(target=randomnumstreamloop,args=())]][0]
```

Client.py ish

```
import socket
UDP_IP = socket.gethostname()
UDP_PORT = 42096
place=(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT)
tube = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
tube.bind(place)

import pickle
def unbox(box):
    mail=pickle.loads(box)
    data=mail['d']
    num=pickle.loads(data)
    return num

data, addr = tube.recvfrom(1024)

fresh=0
doit=True
def thefreshest():
    data, addr = tube.recvfrom(1024)
    global fresh
    fresh=unbox(data)
    global doit
    doit=True
    #print(fresh)

thefreshest()
thefreshestgo=True
def thefreshestloop():
    global thefreshestgo
    while thefreshestgo:
        thefreshest()
    print("endingfreshestloop")
    thefreshestgo=True

import threading
thefreshestloophandler=[[thread,thread.start()] for thread in [threading.Thread(target=thefreshestloop,args=())]][0]

def fibonacci(n): 
    a = 0
    b = 1
    if n < 0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
    elif n == 0: 
        return a 
    elif n == 1: 
        return b 
    else: 
        for i in range(2,n): 
            c = a + b 
            a = b 
            b = c 
        return b

import random
def computationallyexpensive(x):
    return str(fibonacci(250000+int(x*20000)))[::32][:1024]

grindinggo=False
grindinggo=True
def grindingloop():
    global grindinggo
    global doit
    while grindinggo:
        if doit:
            print(computationallyexpensive(fresh))
            doit=False
    print("endinggrindingloop")
    grindgo=True

grindinghandler=[[thread,thread.start()] for thread in [threading.Thread(target=grindingloop,args=())]][0]
```

The way I solve this problem currently is with two threads, one thread constantly updating the variable `freshest` and another thread operating on it. Is there a way to grab all the UDP datagrams available, like recvall() with TCP, so I don't need to make a separate thread? I understand that UDP is datagram based and TCP is stream based.

The code is functional, but if there was a way to either 1. grab all the udp packets in one big chunk or 2. grab only the most recent udp packet and throw awa the rest, I could make my code much more neat and efficient.

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working? Because your code does exactly what it's designed to do, send and recieve data. So it would be nice if you explained what isn't working with your code, what's the intended outcome that you can't achieve with this code? Also there's no [recvall()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120761/why-does-python-socket-library-not-include-recvall-method-like-sendall) in Python, so I'm a bit confused as to what you need.

Comment: sorry, edited my answer.